# Why does my Manifest declared broadcast receiver listening to an explicit broadcast stop working after a while?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

I m trying to create two apps that communicate by one of them receiving a broadcast of the other.
The sending App A has a lot of permissions and sends out these broadcasts in all kinds of low power mode Situations (deep doze,light doze,...). App B has nothing running but an manifest declared Receiver which receives the broadcasts and does some work. 
Once i have opened and closed the receiving app, this works fine for a day or more and then suddenly the receiver stops receiving. I say it stops receiving because even if the phone is turned on and attached for debugging, my adb bridge dosn't show its process when i send the broadcast. Its normal that it doesn't show a process since theres nothing running but once i call the receiver it usually showed a process in the debugger while it worked. Once it stops working this process doesn't pop up and i see no side effects of the receiver working.

receiver in manifest of App B

```xml
     <receiver
            android:name=".MyReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.NOTIFICATIONBROADCSTACTION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

In App A I tried with a normal broadcast and an ordered Broadcast. Both times the problem occured after some time. I used the ordered broadcast thinking the wakelock of the receiver might be running out. This is why i m holding a partial wakelock until my receiver for the ordered broadcast returns. However since it dosn't seam to be called in the first place this shouldn't change anything.

```java
 Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("com.example.NOTIFICATIONBROADCSTACTION");
        putIntentExtras(intent,m);
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> infos = packageManager.queryBroadcastReceivers(intent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo info : infos) {
            ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(info.activityInfo.packageName,
                    info.activityInfo.name);
                    intent.setComponent(cn);
            //sendBroadcast(intent);
            sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null, bc,null, MainActivity.RESULT_CANCELED,null,null);

        }
```

I have the feeling that android marks my receiver as inactive or removes it if the user dosn't interact with it for a while. 
Since manifest declared receivers require that the app has to be opened atleast once for it to be registered at OS i feel like this requirment is kind of beeing reset after a while by timing out the receiver.
Does anyone know whats happening and why my receiver stops working?
And if so do you have an approach to resolving this.

It is important to mention that App B may not have any permissions that require user confirmation, yet still please leave a comment if you have a solution which includes this.

Comment: so i have found a possible explanation which i m currently testing.
Application B gets a lot of notifications in my current implementation and always dismisses them.
I suspect that App B is beeing put into a low priority standby bucket like Rare or Restricted since the user never clicks the notifications in my testing.
This leads to android os maybe deciding not to provide the resources required for my receiver.
This also would explain why i runs perfectly again once the app was opened putting it back in a higher bucket.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue by putting app B into less important buckets via ADB command: adb shell am set-standby-bucket packagename active|working_set|frequent|rare|45. (45=restricted)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the Flag `Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES`.